# What is the scope of a dependency with a singleton lifestyle used in a component with a scoped lifestyle?

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor

On the same container, per web request.

Are they equivalent in this context?   That is, does the singleton effectively become scoped to the lifetime of the scoped component,as it were? Or is it truly a singleton (spanning multiple web requests).

There is nothing in the expansive Castle Windsor docs which helps out here,

EDIT:  Composition of Container

Controller  <- Service A   ( <- means is dependent on)

Service A <- Session A

Command <- Session A

BeginScope() is called upon each request for a controller

Controller is scoped

Service A is singleton

Session A is scoped

Command is scoped

Are Service A and Session A equivalently scoped in this scenario?

Comment: Could you give an example of setting up the lifestyles/scopes as you describe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component registration determines lifestyle. A component registered with singleton lifestyle will be reused until the container in which it is registered in is disposed regardless of what other components it is injected into.

If another component with per web request lifecycle requires it, the same instance of the singleton will be injected on every web request.

Response to edit:

Service A is instantiated once. Session A gets the same instance of Service A every time. Command gets a new instance of Session A per web request.

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, regardless of what the consumer of a dependecy has its lifstyle set to, if the dependency is registered with a singleton lifestyle, its lifestyle can not be determined by any consumer. It is truly a singleton for the lifetime of the container?

Comment: Yes that's basically it.

Comment: Ok this contradicts some ArchScience I heard (think BroScience but relating to Architects)  Given the lack of documentation and tinkering I couldn't confirm this either way. Thanks

Comment: Well, it should be pretty quick to convince yourself with test code!

Comment: Its mean to be the other way around, that is controller is dependent on a "stateless" service A...Does that clear it up?

Comment: Cool, sorry, deleted my comment while I reworded it, so Controller -> Service A

Answer (score 1):

You have an error here where some components are registered with shorter lifestyles that other components which depend on them. This is an example of the "captive dependency problem" which Mark Seemann wrote about recently here: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/.

For example:

Service A <- Session A

when

Service A is singleton and Session A is scoped.

This means that the first time Service A is requested it will be created and its dependency Session A will be created. Service A now stores a reference to its Session A.

But, since Service A is registered as Singleton, every time you request it you will get back the actual same object, and that will have the actual same reference to Session A as the first time.

This will cause you potentially serious and subtle bugs in the long run, and means you have to be very careful with your registrations and lifestyles. Castle Windsor now has some means of detecting these lifestyle misconfigurations, I think. See Mark Seemann's post for more info.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I acually wasn't supposed to -1 you!! Will change that when I can.

Comment: My read of the question (which was a little confusing) was that by `Service A <- Session A` OP meant "Session A is dependent on Service A" - i.e. Session A requires a Service A to be injected. This follows the typical convention of a dependency arrow leading from the dependent entity to the dependency. I think this makes more sense given the name of the components, and it's how I interpreted the question. All that notwithstanding, you point out a useful issue definitely worth understanding.